# How to disable read permission on couchdb database

Tags: nosql, couchdb, distributed-computing, database-replication, couchdb-python

The problem is I have multiple couchdb local clients databases say **A_db**, **B_db**, **C_db** which is replicating to a couchdb server master database says **server_db**. Now each client is creating a document say **A_doc**, **B_doc**, **C_doc** in their local db which automatically replicating to server_db. So now server_db will have 3 documents, one for each client.
Since every client can see all documents of server_db using

> server_db/_all_docs?include_docs=true

But I want to restrict clients to read/write other client documents which is on server_db. And only server_db admin to view documents all documents.

Answer (score 1):

Document level read restriction is not supported by CouchDB. I point you to a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418700/couchdb-read-write-restrictions-on-users-database):

The suggested pattern is to have a db per user or db per role as it seems you are doing.

You should restrict the access to server_db only to authorized users, not to clients.

Some helpful links:

- [Cloudant Envoy](https://github.com/cloudant-labs/envoy)
- [Offile wep apps with CouchDB and PouchDB](https://subvisual.co/blog/posts/130-how-to-build-offline-web-applications-with-couchdb-and-pouchdb/)
- [DB per user](https://www.titrias.com/how-to-pouchdb-couchdb-database-per-user-made-simple/)

Comment: But if i restrict server_db to authorised users (admin), will clients be able to replicate their dbs to server_db?

Comment: Each client should replicate with its own database in the server, i.e. A_db local db should replicate to A_db server db. Then you can do a server side sync between de server client db and the centralized server database.

Comment: Is there is another way if we don't want to create client db copies at server, I mean directly from client local db to centralized server db?

Comment: And secondly I am not able to create local client db copy on server with non-admin user privilege during replication.

Comment: You will need some server side logic to implement the pattern. I include some links in the answer.